# How to check if there is space available to add a view in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, hstack

I am trying to achieve this layout seen in iMessage Group Chat with user icons overlayed on top of each other. Except that these views need to be inside a NavigationLink embedded in a List to make things simpler.

[image: Ideal UI]image source: https://appletoolbox.com/how-to-use-imessage-group-chat/

I have created these round views using SwiftUI `Text` and clipping using circular shape.

The problem is: If there isn't enough space horizontally, how can I limit the number of round views? If I had 10 round views, but a compact width device, I'd only want to show N number of views that will prevent clipping views (please refer attached image below). Not aiming for scrolling either. For given example I am trying to layout only 4 views if they can fit in the given space and completely not add other view to the view hierarchy. Round views can have a min height of 100 and aspect ratio of 1.

Here's my SwiftUI view that you can copy in Xcode that inherits Layout. [Article on composing custom layouts with SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/composing_custom_layouts_with_swiftui)

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  SiwftuiTutorial
//

import SwiftUI

struct HorizontalOffsetLayoutView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: {
                    Text("destination")
                }) {
                    HStackOffsetLayout {
                        Text("AB")
                            .font(.title)
                            .padding(20)
                            .background(Color.orange)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                            .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 3))
                        
                        Text("CD")
                            .font(.title)
                            .padding(20)
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .background(Color.red)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                            .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 3))
                            .opacity(1)
                        Text("EF")
                            .font(.title)
                            .padding(20)
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .background(Color.green)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                            .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 3))
                            .opacity(1)
                    }
                }
            }.navigationTitle("Users")
        }
    }
}

struct HStackOffsetLayout: Layout {
    func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) -> CGSize {
        
        return CGSize(width: proposal.width ?? .zero, height:  subviews[0].sizeThatFits(.unspecified).height)
    }
    
    func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
        let proposal = ProposedViewSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        
        let standardWidth = subviews[0].sizeThatFits(.unspecified).width
        
        var nextX = bounds.minX + standardWidth / 2 + 5
        let midY = bounds.midY
        for index in subviews.indices {
            subviews[index].place(at: CGPoint(x: nextX, y: midY - 30), proposal: proposal)
            nextX += (standardWidth / 2 + 10)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HorizontalOffsetLayoutView()
    }
}
```

Although adding more than 4 Text views looks bad (last view is clipped off due to list row bounds):

[image]

How can I limit the number of views displayed even though there are more subviews requested? As shown in the expected UI image, how can I limit the views to only 4 views, even if there are 6 views added to the `HStackOffsetLayout` for a compact width device, but if larger space is offered by the layout (for ex. iPad) display more views that fit the entire list row. FYI By not calling the `placesubviews(in:proposal:subviews:cache:)` the subviews still get added to the view hierarchy.

Is this even the ideal approach (using Layout)? Open to considering other solutions.

Expected UI (for example with 4 views). All Views are Equal Width & Height & no views are clipped:

[image: consistent UI]

Comment: Look at `ViewThatFits`

Comment: Appreciate your response. Do you mean to use that in the Custom Layout or wrap individual view in the view body?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe place the views off screen, if they are beyond some margin from the max bounds.  Like this...

```
for index in subviews.indices {
    if nextX < bounds.maxX - 60 {
        subviews[index].place(at: CGPoint(x: nextX, y: midY - 30), proposal: proposal)
    } else {
        subviews[index].place(at: CGPoint(x: -999, y: midY - 30), proposal: proposal)
    }
    nextX += (standardWidth / 2 + 10)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I was thinking of something that would prevent rendering the unnecessary views, as these can quickly grow in number, say 20 per list item.